# Scala check if string in option is defined and empty

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
myOption: Option[String]
```

What is the most idiomatic way to check if the String value inside the Option is empty (if its not defined, then it should be considered empty)?

Is `myOption.getOrElse("").isEmpty` the best / cleanest way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do

```
def foo(s: Option[String]) = s.forall(_.isEmpty)
```

Or

```
def foo(s: Option[String]) = s.fold(true)(_.isEmpty)
```

`fold` has 2 parameters in different lists. The first one is for the `None` case and the other gets evaluated if there is some `String`.

Personally I would prefer the first solution, but the second one makes it very clear that you want to return `true` in case of `None`.

Some examples:

```
foo(Some(""))   //true
foo(Some("aa")) //false
foo(None)       //true
```

Comment: This actually does logically what I need - I needed it to return true in the case of None..my fault since I clarified the question after @Dave's answers

Answer (score 5):

```
myOption.forall(_.isEmpty)
```

The general rule is that for pretty much anything you would want to do with an Option, there's a single method that does it.

Comment: This will yield `false`, when `myOption` is `None`. `myOption.getOrElse("").isEmpty` would yield `true`.

Comment: cool. could you please explain the "_.isEmpty" portion? I see from the type definition that exists takes an a predicate (a function returning a boolean) but I have not encountered the shorthand with the underscore.

Comment: @oym its syntactic sugar for `myOption.exists(x => x.isEmpty)`

Comment: @Kigyo I see. So the underscore is somehow a reference to the outer value?

Comment: `exists` expects a function `String => Boolean` (in this case). The underscore represents the input string parameter.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question on what the None case should be.  Changing it to "forall" instead of "exists" works.  Editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do same using below

```
def foo(s: Option[String]) = s.exists(_.trim.nonEmpty)
```